# the left hand side of a binary predicate issue with BreezeJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze, model-binding

I have run into an issue with a filter predicate using BreezeJS.  When I assign a value to one particular filter of a filter set, I get the client (browser) error: 'The left hand side of a binary predicate cannot be a literal expression, it must be a valid property or functional predicate expression: '

I am also using KnockoutJS, and I have some helper functions to put the predicate(s) together, but, I am not doing anything differently with this particular filter that doesn't work.

I have compared this predicate to one that is created from a different filter that does work, and as far as I can tell, the two predicates are identical in the ways they are supposed to be, and I don't see any discrepancies that should not be there.  One SME suggested checking my casing, but, that is not a problem (that I can tell) - IOW, casing is consistent between the db and the view model.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

The code:

Here is the meta-data being sent by the breeze controller, for the filter that does NOT work (GoofyGuy), and for one that does, so you can see the metadata is basically identical

```
{
 "name": "GoofyGuy",
 "type": "Edm.String",
 "nullable": "false",
 "maxLength": "256",
 "fixedLength": "false",
 "unicode": "true"
},
{
 "name": "Priority",
 "type": "Edm.String",
 "nullable": "false",
 "maxLength": "256",
 "fixedLength": "false",
 "unicode": "true"
},
```

Here is the html binding:

```
<select data-bind="value: GoofyGuy().filterValue">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option>Approval Hold</option>
  <option>Approved</option>
  <option>Deleted</option>
  <option>Executed</option>
  <option>Execution Hold</option>
  <option>Off Hold</option>
  <option>Submitted</option>
  <option>Verification Hold</option>
  <option>Verified</option>
 </select>
```

Here is the model:

```
function Filter_ChangeRequest(canViewOthers) {
var self = this;
self.filterName = '',
self.filterType = 'changeRequest',
    self.dateCreated = ko.observable('');
self.isActive = ko.observable(true),
self.submitter = ko.observable(new FilterValue()),
self.deadline = ko.observable(new FilterComparison()),
self.priority = ko.observable(new FilterValue()),
self.GoofyGuy = ko.observable(new FilterValue()),
self.requestId = ko.observable(new FilterValue()),
self.itemTitle = ko.observable(new FilterValue()),
self.domain = ko.observable(new FilterValue()),
self.policyWaiver = ko.observable(new FilterValue()),
self.submitDate = ko.observable(new FilterComparison()),
self.approvedBy = ko.observable(new FilterValue()),
self.description = ko.observable(new FilterValue()),
self.canViewOthers = canViewOthers,
self.submitters = ['amr\\maburke', 'amr\\jdkraft'],
self.idsid = '';

self.setInitialValues = function () {
    self.submitter(new FilterValue('SubmittedByIdsid'));
    self.deadline(new FilterComparison('DeadlineRequested'));
    self.priority(new FilterValue('Priority'));
    self.GoofyGuy(new FilterValue('GoofyGuy'));
    self.requestId(new FilterValue('RequestId'));
    self.itemTitle(new FilterValue('Title'));
    self.domain(new FilterValue('Domain'));
    self.policyWaiver(new FilterValue('IncludesPolicyWaiver'));
    self.submitDate(new FilterComparison('SubmitDate'));
    self.approvedBy(new FilterValue('ApprovedBy'));
    self.description(new FilterValue('Description'));
    self.submitters = ['amr\\maburke', 'amr\\jdkraft'];
};

self.init = function () {
    self.setInitialValues();


};
self.clear = function () {
    self.setInitialValues();
};

self.populate = function (filterValues) {
    if (self.canViewOthers)
        self.submitter().populate(filterValues.submitter);
    self.deadline().populate(filterValues.deadline);
    self.priority().populate(filterValues.priority);
    //self.GoofyGuy().populate(filterValues.GoofyGuy);
    self.requestId().populate(filterValues.requestId);
    self.itemTitle().populate(filterValues.itemTitle);
    self.domain().populate(filterValues.domain);
    self.policyWaiver().populate(filterValues.policyWaiver);
    self.submitDate().populate(filterValues.submitDate);
    self.approvedBy().populate(filterValues.approvedBy);
    self.description().populate(filterValues.description);
};

self.breezeFilter = function () {
    var filterPredicates = ko.observableArray([]);
    //breezeUtils.addPredicate(self.submitter(), filterPredicates);
    //breezeUtils.addPredicate(self.deadline(), filterPredicates);

    //if (self.stateX().filterValue() == '')
    //    //add != Deleted predicate
    //    filterPredicates.push(breeze.Predicate.create('StateNameX', breeze.FilterQueryOp.NotEquals, 'Deleted'));
    //else
    breezeUtils.addPredicate(self.GoofyGuy(), filterPredicates);
    //breezeUtils.addPredicate(self.priority(), filterPredicates);
    //breezeUtils.addPredicate(self.itemTitle(), filterPredicates);
    //breezeUtils.addPredicate(self.domain(), filterPredicates);
    //breezeUtils.addPredicate(self.policyWaiver(), filterPredicates);
    //breezeUtils.addPredicate(self.submitDate(), filterPredicates);
    //breezeUtils.addPredicate(self.approvedBy(), filterPredicates);
    //breezeUtils.addPredicate(self.description(), filterPredicates);
    //breezeUtils.addPredicate(self.requestId(), filterPredicates);

    return breeze.Predicate.and(filterPredicates());

}
};
```

And then these are the helper functions to pop the predicates:

```
var breezeUtils = {
Predicate: breeze.Predicate,
FilterQueryOp: breeze.FilterQueryOp,
addPredicate: function (filter, predicateCollection) {
    if (filter.filterValue()) {
        //if there is a filter value, add it to the predicate collection
        predicateCollection.push(this.getPredicate(filter));
    }
},
getPredicate: function (filter) {
    if (filter.hasOwnProperty('boundary') && filter.boundary()) { //compound predicate
        var p1 = this.Predicate.create(filter.title, this.FilterQueryOp.GreaterThanOrEqual, filter.filterValue());
        var p2 = this.Predicate.create(filter.title, this.FilterQueryOp.LessThanOrEqual, filter.boundary());
        return this.Predicate.and([p1, p2]);
    }
    var operator = this.getQueryOperator(filter.valueComparison());
    return this.Predicate.create(filter.title, operator, filter.filterValue());
},
```

Finally, here is the predicate set before it gets sent to the server to illustrate the two filters are again basically identical:

[image]

In comment below, I indicated that even after changing everything on the server and client to use 'goofy', I still get the same error:
[image]

Comment: In making a few more changes and looking at the network panel in dev tools, this error is thrown before the query is sent to the controller to be executed - it's wholly a client issue.

Comment: I figured out the issue.  I had changed the entity I was using to pop the UI from a base table, to a composed view.  The action on the breeze controller had the same name as the underlying table entity.  When I updated the underlying source, I changed the action to return the correct type collection, but, the action name remained the same.  Thus, when it came time to create the predicate, the defaultResourceName created by breeze was still the old entity, not the new one.  Just so happened this was the only filter that would illustrate this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Casing *does* look different between GoofyGuy and everything else.  E.g.:

```
self.priority(new FilterValue('Priority'));
self.GoofyGuy(new FilterValue('GoofyGuy'));
```

I think Breeze is camelCasing the name (using the NamingConvention), and then attempting to match the (client-side) property name.  So:

```
"Priority" -> priority // works
"GoofyGuy" -> goofyGuy // Breeze can't find the property
```

Change `self.GoofyGuy` to `self.goofyGuy` everywhere, and that should fix it.

Comment: I'll see if that particular change helps.  I'm 99% sure that it had been goofyGuy before I changed it to all caps, the reason I can't say for sure is that initially, the column was called 'State', and the corresponding js object property was 'state', so I changed it to avoid possible collisions in the breeze library, but it went through a couple of permutations already.  Your suggestion does make me think that I need to review ALL of my casings though, so, I'll try some things and post my results, if any.

Comment: I changed EF model to use 'Goofy', and changed the client side to use 'goofy', and that resulted in the same error being thrown.  Other filters where the server property is one word capitalized, and the client side one word lowercased, work, such as in the above - 'Priority'

Comment: This is disheartening: changed the server-side property to 'goofy', and even with client-side property being 'goofy', still get the same error.